# $2^p =\#G_{2^p-1} \implies 2^{p}-1$ prime

Tags: group-theory, number-theory, prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

I've been stuck on trying to prove this conjecture I have for a while and I was hoping maybe someone had a useful insight. I have the group $G_n=\{(a,b)\pmod{n}  |  a^2 - 3b^2 \equiv 1 \pmod{n} \}$, with the group law $(a,b)*(c,d) = (ac+3bd,ad+bc)$, and I want to examine the case when $n=2^p -1$ for some prime $p$.

While trying to prove another result, I realized I needed this result in particular, that
$2^p = \#G_{2^p -1} \implies 2^p -1$ is prime. I'm not sure whether or  not it is even true, but I wrote some python code to check, and I have a strong suspicion that it is.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming that you know a bit of algebraic number theory. It particular, I will use freely the fact that $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{3}]$ and ramification theory in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3})/\mathbb{Q}$.

Since you want $n$ to be of the form $2^p-1$, assuming that $p>2$ (I let you handle the case $p=2$, that is $n=3$), we have $n\equiv -1 [4]$ and $n\equiv 1 [3] $. The Jacobi symbol of $3$ mod $n$ is then $-1$, meaning that $3$ is not a square mod $n$.

It follows that $G_n$ is the kernel of the norm map $S^\times \to R^\times$, where $R=\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ and  $S=R[\sqrt{3}]$.

**Lemma 1.**  We have $\vert G_n\vert= \frac{\vert S^\times\vert}{\vert R^\times \vert}$

**Proof.** Unfortunately, I only have sophisticated arguments for this lemma.

Note that since $6\nmid n$, the extension $S/R$ is a quadratic étale ring extension.

Now, since $R$ is finite, $R$ is the direct product of finitely many local rings . In particular, its Picard group is trivial and it is known that in this case, Hilbert 90 holds: an element of $x\in S^\times $ has norm $1$ if and only if $x=\frac{\bar{y}}{y}$ for some $y\in S^\times$, where $\bar{\phantom{}}$ is the unique non trivial $R$-automorphism of $S$.

The kernel of the map $y\mapsto S^\times\to \frac{\bar{y}}{y}\in S^\times$ is $R^\times$ ,and its image is $G_n$. Finally, we get $\vert G_n\vert= \frac{\vert S^\times\vert}{\vert R^\times \vert}$.

**Lemma 2.** If $A$ is a UFD and $\pi$ is a prime element such that $A/\pi$ is finite, then for all $m\geq 1$, we have $\vert (A/\pi^m)^\times\vert =(\vert A/\pi\vert -1)\vert\cdot \vert A/\pi\vert ^{m-1}$.

**Proof.** We have an exact sequence $1\to (1+\pi^m A)/\pi^{m+1}\to (A/\pi^{m+1})^\times\to (A/\pi^m)^\times \to 1$

Since $(1+a\pi^m)(1+b\pi^m)=1+(a+b)\pi^m \mod \pi^{m+1}$, the group $(1+\pi^m A)/\pi^{m+1}$ is isomorphic to $A/\pi$. Now apply induction.

Note now that $S\simeq \mathbb{Z[\sqrt{3}]}/(n)$.

Now, by assumption $n$ is divisible by primes different from $2$ and $3$, so $p$ is congruent to $\pm 1$ mod $3$.

If $p\equiv -1 [3]$, it is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{3}]$, and $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{3}]/(p)\simeq \mathbb{F}_{p^2}$. Hence $\vert(\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{3}]/(p^m))^\times\vert =(p^2-1)p^{2(m-1)}$.

If $p\equiv 1 [3]$, it splits as $p=\pi\bar{\pi}$, and  $\pi$ and $\bar{\pi}$ are non associate. We have $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{3}]/(\pi)\simeq \mathbb{F}_{p}$, and same for $\bar{\pi}$. Now $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{3}]/(p^m)\simeq \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{3}]/(\pi^m)\times \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{3}]/(\bar{\pi}^m)$ as rings,so it induces a group isomorphism between units, and  we get $\vert(\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{3}]/(p^m))^\times\vert =(p-1)^2p^{2(m-1)}$.

**Thm.** Assume that $n\equiv -1 [4]$ and $n\equiv 1 [3] $. Then $$\vert G_n\vert =\displaystyle ( \prod_{p\mid n, p\equiv -1 [3]}(p+1)p^{v_p(n)-1})( \prod_{p\mid n, p\equiv 1 [3]}(p-1)p^{v_p(n)-1})$$

**Proof.** Note that a Bezout relation in $\mathbb{Z}$ is also a Bezout relation in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{3}]$. Hence if two integers $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}$ are coprime , then $(a)$ and $(b)$ are comaximal $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{3}]$.

Now apply Chinese theorem and the previous considerations, together with Lemma 1, and the fact that $\vert R^\times\vert=\varphi(n)$.

The formula above then implies that, if $G_n$ has order a power of $2$, then $n$ is a product of pairwise distinct prime numbers, and a prime divisor $p$ is either a Mersenne prime if $p\equiv 1 [3]$ or a Fermat prime if $p\equiv -1 [3]$.

Thus:

**Cor.** Assume that $n\equiv -1 [4]$ and $n\equiv 1 [3] $. Then $G_n$ is a $2$-group if and only $n=M_1 \cdots M_r F_1...F_s$, where $M_i$ is a Mersenne prime and $F_j$ is a Fermat prime, and all primes are pairwise distinct. In this case, $\vert G_n\vert =(M_1+1)\cdots(M_r+1)(F_1-1)\cdots (F_s-1)$.

**Final comment.** What is left to do is to convince yourself that , if $n=2^p-1$, this last product is $2^p=n+1$ if and only if $n$ is a Mersenne prime, or equivalently, if $n$ has two distinct prime factors, then $\vert G_n\vert \neq n+1$. This is not totally clear to me, and it's getting late here...I leave it to you.

Comment: Wow I think I might be really out of my depth even beginning to trying to understand your answer :o. Even though I don't understand much of the content, your final comment helped clarify some things for me. I'm only a second year undergrad so maybe when I finish I'll come back to this :)

I very much appreciate the time you put into this though, I might show this to one of my profs and see the response!